# Hangouts Chat Bot - Thread message posting above the thread's last message

Tags: google-hangouts

I created a simple hangout's chat bot. When posting back to the thread, when setting the ThreadId, the message appears ABOVE the last message instead of below.  If I remove the threadid it posts as a normal message below the thread.  I'm not sure what I'm missing or even why the service would let me inject a message above the last one?

The code is pretty simple:

```
var response = ParseAndRespond(msg);
var chatMessage = new Message();
chatMessage.Text = response;
if (msg.message.thread != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg.message.thread.name))
 {
   chatMessage.Thread = new Google.Apis.HangoutsChat.v1.Data.Thread();
                        chatMessage.Thread.Name = msg.message.thread.name;

 }

 var request = ChatClient.Spaces.Messages.Create(chatMessage, msg.message.space.name);
 request.Execute();
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No I didn't and because of the bugs we switched to slack.